# Accessing ItemType methods within Stack

Tags: java

I'm having trouble accessing a method in my ItemType class, from a Stack of ItemTypes.

My ItemType class is very simple

```
 public class SteveItemType{

    private String name;


   public SteveItemType(String name){
  this.name = name;
  }
       public String getName(){
  return this.name;
  }

  }
```

My toString method from my Stack class:

```
    public String toString(){
      return stack[top].getName();  }
```

This is where my error is hiding. I believe whats being stored inside my stack is not an object type (which is disabling me from accessing my getName method)

My Bounded Stack constructors are:

```
public ArrayStack(){
      stack = (SteveItemType[]) new Object[default_cap]; }

   public ArrayStack(int n){
      stack = (SteveItemType[]) new Object[n];  }
```

Finally in my application, this is how I am pushing my ItemType & creating my stack:

```
ArrayStack stack = new ArrayStack<SteveItemType>(n);

stack.push(new SteveItemType("Steve"));
```

My error is

```
> ArrayStack.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
>          return stack[top].getName();
```

Please if anyone could explain why/where my logic/thinking is wrong I very appreciate it, my apologies for all the moving parts I try to make as precise as possible.

(I am unable to access my getName method)

Comment: You've left out a lot of relevant code. Where is `stack` declared? What is `top`?

Comment: `(SteveItemType[]) new Object[default_cap]` should throw a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Could you please post `ArrayStack.java`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please following snippet of code as applicable in `ArrayStack.java`:

```
public class ArrayStack<T extends SteveItemType> {

private SteveItemType[] stack;  
private int top;    
private int default_cap=5;

public ArrayStack(){
      stack = new SteveItemType[default_cap]; 
  }

public ArrayStack(int size) {
    this.stack = new SteveItemType[size];
  }

public String toString(){
      return stack[top].getName();
  }

public void push(T t){
    // push an object
  } 
  // more methods follows
}
```

Explanation:

The above class is defined using a bounded type parameter. The type parameter's name is `T`. It is followed by the extends keyword. This is again followed by its upper bound, which is here `SteveItemType`.

```
public class ArrayStack<T extends SteveItemType> { }
```

This ensures that `T` is at least of type `SteveItemType`. `T` might also be a sub-type of `SteveItemType`. All of this gurantees that from within `ArrayStack`, we can treat `T` as if it is `SteveItemType` and can use all of the methods that belong to `SteveItemType`. So we may define the following without any type-casting:

```
public String toString(){
      return stack[top].getName();
  }
```

Comment: Works! Thank you! If you have time could you please explain why?!

Comment: Could you please have a look at the `Explanation` section of my answer?